# I having trouble of how to play the trill along with the grace note in this piece, how do I play it?

Tags: double-bass

[image]

Playing grace notes is fairly new to me, so understand how much value the dotted quarter gets with the grace is confusing. There's no recording of this piece that I could find so I thought I should ask some people what it should sound like.

Piece is from the book "12 Bass Studies" - 2nd etude

Comment: Regardless of the obscurity of this piece, what's its name? Perhaps someone else who visits this website has played it and can help you.

Comment: There are no strict rules how fast trills have to be played and where they start. I would start with agagfg and finish with the 2 grace notes (like a turn).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How many note you play in the trill will depend on the tempo. But however many notes you play the last two will be the grace notes. If the piece is classical, you would start the trill on the upper note.

Some examples:
[image]

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand it, I made a audio clip to confirm if this is what it should be sounding like https://sndup.net/8zgw

Comment: Another issue is HOW do you play it physically.  I don't think you are high enough to be playing with the thumb.  Are you able to finger this phrase w/o shifting?

Comment: @Proudone5 It looks like you're on the right track.

Comment: I like this approach.   If the tempo is below andante, the last version "feels" good.  But even at very slow tempi,  probably not more than 3 reps before the grace notes.

Comment: The tempo is around 55-65BPM for dotted quarter note, so I think I'll have enough time to shift back up

Comment: By "reps" do you mean a pair of B to C notes?

Comment: @Proudone5 yep, exactly